# Eclipse's errors of the Android Design Support library

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to import into eclipse the library "android.support.design", but after importation I get a few errors:

```
/design/res/values/styles.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:23: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:34: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'. 
/design/res/values/styles.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:59: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:67: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.      
/design/res/values/styles.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.     
/design/res/values/styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.     
/design/res/values/styles.xml:91: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'. 
/design/res/values/styles.xml:103: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.  
/design/res/values/styles.xml:111: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'. 
/design/res/values/styles.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:23: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:34: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.  
/design/res/values/styles.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:59: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:67: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:91: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:103: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
/design/res/values/styles.xml:111: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
```

How can I fix?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you import the resources file? Also I suggest you swithing to Android Studio.

Comment: Ciao Gabriele,
Ho provato ad utilizzare Android Studio ma preferisco continuare con Eclipse. Per l'importazione faccio in questo modo:

File -> Import -> Existing Android Code into Workspace -> /android-sdk/extras/android/support/design

Come faccio con ad esempio google-play-services_lib o la libreria cardview_v7

Answer (score 5):

According to this Android Developer Blog for Android Design Support Library, Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries are the dependencies to build the Design Support library.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

So in Eclipse, Right Click on the android support design library project -> Properties -> Android, go to Library section on the bottom, and click Add.. to add your AppCompat Library to the project.

Comment: Same errors but I solved using this: https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design

Answer (score 3):

add this in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

in eclipse: (add all above jar)

```
Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> yourjar.jar
```